# Pure C: trim all characters in a string after a word occurs

Tags: c, string, character

I have a character array in C that can have a value such as `/path/example/abc`. I want it so that any characters after the `/path/example/` part get gobbled up, reallocating the string for its new size. Is there a standard function, or function you could write that can accomplish this? Perhaps this could be accomplished with a library like *PCRE*? **Note**: Pure, platform-independent C code would be appreciated.

**Example**:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100] = "I am a string";
    newStr = globbleAfter(str, "I am a");
    printf("%s\n", newStr); 
    return 0;
}

//=> "I am a"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRCE seems overkill for this. Just use strstr to find newStr within str. Example:

```
char *gobbleAfter(char *string, char *pattern) {
    int len;
    char *gobbled;
    char *pos=strstr(string, pattern);
    if (pos==NULL)
        return NULL;
    if ((gobbled=malloc(len=((pos-string)+strlen(pos)+1)))==NULL)
        return NULL; /* or maybe call an out of memory handler */
    memcpy(gobbled, string, len-2);
    gobbled[len-1]='\0';
    return gobbled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since functions like printf work on zero-terminated strings, it is enough to set the first not-needed character to zero. Something like `str[strlen("I am a")] = 0`. It modifies the original string though. And most importantly it is not safe - before setting to zero you should check if the length of your substring is not greater than the length of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

@Wojtek Surowka Without checking for the pattern within the original string there might be an instance where the pattern is not contained in the original string.  There is also an issue if the pattern is found at some offset within the string.

```
String = "bob is running"
Pattern1 = "frank"
Pattern2 = "is run"
```

@Guntram Blohm After you malloc when do you free the allocated memory?

> if ((gobbled=malloc(len=((pos-string)+strlen(pos)+1)))==NULL)

This method relies on src being less than 260 characters. It will not alter the original string.

This function is incorrect

```
#define MAX_PATH 260
char* gobbleAfter(const char* src, const char* pattern)
{
  int len = strlen(pattern);
  int cpy_len;
  char[MAX_PATH] gobbled_string;
  char* pos = strstr(src, pattern);

  gobbled_string[0] = '\0';

  if(pos)//null check
  {
    cpy_len = (pos - string) + len + 1
    if(cpy_len <= MAX_PATH)
    {
      memcpy(gobbled_string, src, cpy_len);
    }
  }
  return gobbled_string;
}
```

if you don't mind changing the source

```
char* gobbleAfter(char* src, const char* pattern)
{
  char* gobbled_string = NULL;
  char* temp = strstr(src, pattern);
  if(temp)
  {
    gobbled_string = src;
    gobbled_string[temp - src + strlen(pattern)] = '\0';
  }
  return gobbled_string;
}
```

Comment: Buck, your char[MAX_PATH] will allocate the string on the stack, where it will get overwritten as soon as the calling function calls something else. To your question "when do i free the allocated memory?": I don't. The caller is responsible for doing that when he doesn't need the string anymore, obviously, the function can't know when. I can't free the original string either, as that might not even have been *x*alloc'ed in the first place.

Comment: Guntram, you are correct. gobbled_string would be allocated on the stack and would be overwritten, which is my mistake. Generally when I create these small auxiliary functions I try to stay away from allocating memory that I don't free, so a user doesn't have to keep track of memory they are not allocating.

Comment: You're right when you try to avoid that, because it's just too easy to introduce memory leaks this way. I agree that "the user must free the returned string when he stops using it" belongs in the documentation for functions like this. Unfortunately, there's no real alternative, as the caller doesn't know the length of the returned string, so you can't just have him provide a pre-alloc'ed string of appropriate size. Things like this, you can't do well, you can just try to decide which evil is the least.